# Замена всех значений в столбце MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: ЧТО делать та]

Как можно массово заменить значения даты в столбце?

Comment: сделать `UPDATE`

Comment: UPDATE <имя таблицы> SET date_exp=<нужное значение>

Comment: UPDATE t2gj_items SET `date_exp` = '2027-02-02 02:02:02' 
Получилось вот таким способом